# Understanding Export a round bracket function in ES6

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, export

I am trying to understand following export statement:

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="about" component={AboutPage}/>
    </Route>
);
```

By definition, The export statement is used to export functions, objects, or primitive values.

**Different Syntax**:

> ```
> export { name1, name2, …, nameN };
> export { variable1 as name1, variable2 as name2, …, nameN };
> export let name1, name2, …, nameN; // also var, function
> export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN; // also var, const
>
> export default expression;
> export default function (…) { … } // also class, function*
> export default function name1(…) { … } // also class, function*
> export { name1 as default, … };
>
> export * from …;
> export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;
> export { import1 as name1, import2 as name2, …, nameN } from …;
> ```

Among all of possible alternatives I am not able to relate how export default ( .. ); fit in.

I am guessing it would be exporting an anonymous function.

Comment: It's a parenthesized expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This rule applies:

```
export default expression;
```

`(...)` is the [**grouping operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping), which is an expression. It simply evaluates to the result of the expression it contains. You surely have seen it before. For example:

```
(20 + 1) * 2
```

Some constructs require an expression to be started on the same line. In the following example, the function returns `undefined`, because the expression has to start in the same line as the `return`:

```js
function foo() {
  return
    21 + 1;
}

console.log(foo());
```

With the grouping operator, we can do exactly that: Start the expression on the same line, but put the main part on the next line, for stylistic reasons:

```js
function foo() {
  return (
    21 + 1
  );
}

console.log(foo());
```

---

I don't know whether or not using the grouping operator is required in the `export default` case, but it would be trivial to find out (run the code with and without it).

Even if it is not required, it doesn't change the result of the expression. Sometimes it's just used to be more visually pleasing or easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @Felix. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you `export default` you give the user the ability to `import NAME from 'module'` where the `NAME` is something the user can choose.
It doesn't really matter what is the name you decided to give what you exported, because it's the default that exported.

Because of that, the user can do:

```
import MyRouter from 'route.js';
```

And it will be exactly the same as

```
import Routing from 'route.js';
```

You can do

```
export default myvar = (<Route...
```

And it would be exactly the same as

```
export default someothervar = (<Route...
```

> Note that when you talk about named exports it does matter

If it wasn't the default - but named value - it does matter, because the `import` is done by name:

```
export {var1, var2, var3}
```

Must be imported as

```
import {var1, var2, var3} from 'myvars.js'
```